# Is there another way to make validation in other page?

Tags: php, validation

hi i tried to make validation using php but i want to do it in another page like (make form action="page.php") and do validation and send data in page.php
but form in page login.html 
i don't like to do all php code in the same page by using PHP_SELF

thanks and sorry for my bad english

html code (login.html)

```
<form class="well" role="form" action="page.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name"/><br><br>
                <span><?php echo $userErr ?></span>
                <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control"placeholder="Password" /><br><br>
                <span><?php echo $passErr ?></span>

                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 45px;"/>
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-info">forget your password?</a>

            </form>
```

---

php code (page.php)

```
$userErr = $passErr = "";
$user = $pass = "";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
   if(empty($_POST['user'])){
$userErr = "Please Insert Your Name";   
}elseif(strlen($_POST['user'])>20){
$userErr = "Your Name Is greater than 20 char";
$user = $_POST['user'];
}
else{
    $user = $_POST['user'];
}
if(empty($_POST['pass'])){
    $passErr ="Pleaes your password";
}
else{
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
}
 }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you try to rephrase your question? (Please use proper punctuation.)

Comment: So what's the problem you're having? Create `page.php`, move your current validation code to that page, and move on.

Comment: @amalMurali when i do like you said i can't echo variable $userErr like image http://i.imgur.com/Zj1OJ1I.jpg .. it get undefined variable

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Post the code for both login.php and page.php

Comment: You say that you want the PHP and HTML on different pages, but the image that you attached in one of your comments clearly shows PHP code within the form.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to decipher your question. Apparently you want to have a form on a page called 'login.html', then have it be validated by a script called 'page.php' and then return to 'login.html', possibly only if validation failed.
This could be accomplished with the header() function. For example, if you want to return to the login.html-page if validation fails:

**page.php**

```
//Validation code here

if ($validated == true)
 {
 //Validation succes
 }
else
 {
 header('Location: login.html');
 }
```

Notice that the header()-function won't work if you already printed something to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**test.php**

```
<?php

// Init
$errors = array();

// Handle Post
if (count($_POST))
{
    // Check Login Fields
    if (empty($_POST['user']))
        $errors['user'] = 'You have not entered user name.';
    else if (strlen($_POST['user']) > 20)
        $errors['user'] = 'Your Name Is greater than 20 char';
    if (empty($_POST['pass']))
        $errors['pass'] = 'You have not entered password.';

    // Proceed If No Erros Occured
    if (!sizeof($errors))
    {
        // do something with the posted data
    }
}

?>

<form class="well" role="form" action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name"/><br><br>
    <span><?php echo isset($errors['user']) ? $errors['user'] : ''; ?></span>
    <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control"placeholder="Password" /><br><br>
    <span><?php echo isset($errors['pass']) ? $errors['pass'] : ''; ?></span>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 45px;"/>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-info">forget your password?</a>
</form>
```

Renders like this when you click submit without filling in the form:

[image]

---

This will probably look correct in your script's context, as I don't have any of your css.

Comment: great .. but i want php code in test.php and html in login.html .